# Erroneous Spam Flag?

Tags: discussion, flags, spam

I've just noticed that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18911977/edit) to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18905686/itunes-review-url-and-ios-7-ask-user-to-rate-our-app-appstore-show-a-blank-pag) was marked as spam and therefore hidden. With the option to view the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18911977/revisions) for details, my curiosity got the better of me.

I was surprised to see that the answer wasn't spam; it was a genuine, though incorrect attempt at an answer.

Especially since the answer was deleted reasonably quickly by a moderator, before I rollback the answer (or any like this in the future), resetting any offensive flags, I'd like to make sure that others agree with me. Should [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/18911977/edit) be rolled back?

Comment: Sounds reasonable, but I doubt we can rollback deleted answers.. ?

Comment: The normal rollback claims to do this.

Comment: There is another post here on Meta about this; if there was just one spam flag before the post being deleted, it is shown with the 'spam hidden' message to those that can still see deleted posts. That is obviously a little too harsh.

Comment: @James true but that's not normal circumstances..

Comment: Found it: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204033/spam-masking-is-over-greedy-please-do-it-only-if-post-received-at-least-3-spam

Comment: @MartijnPieters yeah, was about to mention this either.

Comment: OK, I just tried to rollback. As I expected, nothing happens. We need to flag it and ask to undelete. :)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: There is spam / offensive flag on there that was marked as helpful. This'll take a moderator or dev to fix.

Comment: The *bigger* problem here is that I cannot flag it. There is no `flag` link on such posts.

Comment: I'll ask a new question requesting the feature.

Comment: Do not forget that the system is there to protect the website and its users from becoming a long list of people selling stuff.  There are times when this is going to be wrong and there are even times when another user will have a reason to attack a person's posted answer.  While it is not a perfect system, it is one that has kept the site fairly clean for some years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've gone ahead and cleared out the spam flag on that,since an official Apple product is far from spam. I've left it deleted since it doesn't seem like much of an answer, and more like a new user just throwing out a random link and hoping it sticks.