# Flag erroneous flag

Tags: feature-request, flags, spam

Pertaining to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/207877), we discovered that there is no way to rollback a spam-deleted answer.

Rollback claims to "reset any offensive flags", but this isn't the case.

[image]

---

Can we have a way to **vote to**<sup>1</sup> undo spam-deleted flags / marking them for moderator review please?

<sup>[Servy's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/207886/171964) is pertinent, the solution shouldn't require a single undo/rollback vote else the OP could reintroduce spam content.</sup>

Comment: The action menu is hidden for these as well, right? I thought this may end up being a problem :(

Comment: The "inline, side-by-side" options? No, they're not there either.

Comment: James I think @Oded means edit/undelete/flag actions visible for normally deleted answers.

Comment: Ah, then yes, that's also true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're confused about how the rollback system works here.

The particular post you mentioned only has **one revision**. Therefore, by definition, it cannot be rolled back, because there is not a further revision *to roll back*. You cannot roll back a single revision because it doesn't make sense to roll back a revision *to itself*. Nothing would change.

The rollback-clears-spam-flags feature is to help prevent abuse. It lets spam flags be reversed when spam content was introduced into the post **at a later time**. In essence, the post was not spam, and then became spam, so it makes sense to be able to reverse the spam changes and keep the post in the state where it was acceptable. It is not meant to be a feature where users can go rolling back any post they want to clear out any spam flags, and if it starts getting used that way, the feature will be removed.

In a case where there's only one revision, theoretically it was never acceptable to begin with. That revision is what attracted the spam flag, and if you don't actually reverse any changes (since you can't; there's nothing to reverse), then the spam flags should not be dismissed.

Comment: Then I would suggest the solution involved removing the "rollback" option, replacing it with an "undelete" or "flag for moderator attention"

Comment: As Oded pointed out in the comments, the options are hidden along with the post. I'd consider *that* the problem. You should be able to flag a deleted post. A moderator can easily clear out spam/offensive flags with a couple clicks.

Answer (score 0):

Rollbacks *shouldn't* reset spam/offensive flags.  If there is documentation that says otherwise, it is that documentation that should be changed.

If this indeed happened then people with abusive posts or people making abusive edits could periodically roll back the post and then re-apply the abusive content just to remove offensive flags.

At most, the flags should be elevated to moderator flags, rather than auto-deleting the question at 6 flags.

Comment: The rollback tooltip says this, and so does http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032/what-are-the-spam-and-offensive-flags-and-how-do-they-work It seems to be intentional, designed for situations where a post was vandalized and is receiving flags in its vandalized state.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn Yes, and I'm saying that the tooltips should be changed, rather than the behavior, because that behavior leaves opportunities for abuse.