# Deleted answer marked as spam/offensive on Chrome on phone, but not on Chrome on computer

Tags: bug, deleted-answers

I noticed something odd today after looking at [a deleted answer](https://music.stackexchange.com/a/33843/7222) on my phone and on my laptop both using the chrome browser. On my phone the answer is hidden and marked as spam/offensive, but on my laptop it shows just fine. The post is not locked and it was deleted by the user.

---

### Phone

How the answer appears on Chrome on my phone:

[image: chrome-mobile]

---

### Laptop

How the answer appears on Chrome on my laptop:

[image: chrome-laptop]

---

### Revisions

Here's the revision history:

[image: revision-history]

So there's an inconsistency for some reason.

Comment: The intended behavior is for mods to be shown the content of all deleted posts, even those masked to 10k+ users. This looks like an answer that has [at least one red flag marked helpful on it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/204152/323179). See also [Can we indicate spam masking to mods?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/221105/323179)