# Can we display "see revision history" whenever content has been deleted as spam/offensive?

Tags: feature-request, spam, 10k-tools, offensive

The [new feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131026/remove-links-when-a-post-is-deleted-by-community-from-spam-offensive-flags/199969#199969) that hides the text of a spam or offensive deleted answer isn't being applied every time an answer has been deemed spam or offensive.

The spam/offensive content appears in the revision history only when:

1. Browsing directly to a [question with an answer that was deleted for that reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3740960/raw-input-and-printing-simultaneously/20973016#20973016).
2. Reviewing the flag queue and an answer was deleted you will see:

> [image]

But when you are using the 10k tools to review [New Answers to Old Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/tools/new-answers-old-questions?page=1) any answers flagged and deleted as spam/offensive still show all of the content instead of the revision history message:

> [image]

If we mask the content when you browse to the question and in the flag queue, can we hide the text when it is displayed in other areas like the 10k Tools that display new answers to old questions, etc?

Can we have the new spam/offensive text displayed whenever an answer has been deemed that?

Comment: Wasn't that an audit then?

Comment: What you ask for is profanity filter and honestly I don't think we need such on Stack Overflow. I was sure it was asked before but can't find it, probably it was downvoted and auto-deleted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No it wasn't an audit it was in the New Answers to Old Questions questions 10k tool.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Actually no that isn't what I'm asking for, if an answer has been deleted because it is spam or offensive, I'm asking that the same text is displayed in the New Answers to Old Questions review.  If we are hiding the text when you look at the question, then why aren't we hiding the text when the answer is displayed elsewhere?

Comment: Oh, I see now. Wasn't aware of the tool (which by the way isn't related to review) - the question can probably be edited to be more clear about it e.g. "Make the New Answers to Old Questions 10k tool mask spam answers as well". +1 now. (I originally thought you were asking to blur those words)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I just tried to clear it up a bit (sorry it's way too early here) and I probably shouldn't have tried to ask my feature before caffeine.

Comment: Cheers, also worth to link to the new masking feature.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Added, thanks for the suggestion.  Hopefully this is a bit clearer now. :)

Comment: I don't really get the point of masking it in the first place.

Comment: Can you expedite this request now that you're an employee?