# Obscure the title and text when question is deleted by Community from spam/offensive flags

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, deleted-questions, spam

This is sort of a follow-up to a feature request that resulted in obscuring spam / offensive content from 10K-visible *answers*:
[Remove links when a post is deleted by Community from spam/offensive flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131026/remove-links-when-a-post-is-deleted-by-community-from-spam-offensive-flags)

Suggest the same to be done for questions. As of now, spam questions ([1](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/222067), [2](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/222066)) preserve their titles and content. Suggest to revise the titles to something like

> This question was marked as spam or offensive and is therefore not shown

And the text to something like:

> This question was marked as spam or offensive and is therefore not shown - you can see the revision history for details".

Where "the revision history" links to the question revision history.

---

For those interested, here is a link to screen shots of how spam shines through my flagging summary page and is displayed to me when I click the link to one of deleted questions: **https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfYDS.png**.

For the sake of precision, flagger having less than 10K rep would see only upper screen shot - the one that lists question titles ("Call giRℒs blah blah `<phone number>`") - in their [flagging-summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/flagging-summary/info) page.

Comment: [Seems like](http://i.stack.imgur.com/jfYDS.png) the presence of  in the title should raise a "possible spam" flag ;-)

Comment: Under which circumstances will a regular user stumble upon deleted spam questions?

Comment: ...or, on a more serious note: maybe Unicode in the title should trigger the captcha? Given the user id's in that screenshot, it looks like that spammer just posts as much as the limit allows for, and then creates a new account?

Comment: @MadScientist I sometimes take a look into my flagging summary when in the office, and this is most definitely NSFW: http://i.stack.imgur.com/jfYDS.png - and I guess other 10Kers who flagged this _striptease_, may have this problem, too

Comment: @MadScientist I just checked my flagging summary page at the site where I'm under 10K: title of deleted post is shown to me => that is, any regular user who flagged that spam, will see at least the titles in their flagging history - "Call giRℒs blah blah `<phone number>` blah blah"

Comment: I agree with this so long as the implementation doesn't interfere with the searching of deleted posts - it's handy to be able to check how many times before a given URL has been spammed.

Comment: @Flexo I believe that this has been already addressed when similar feature was implemented for answers; I only propose to extend it to questions

Comment: This is still not done in flag history, which is important part of the request

Comment: @ShadowWizardSaysNoMoreWar I agree, but it's probably better to re-ask that as a separate question now. We don't have a [status-partially-completed] tag ...

Answer (score 18):

I think this is important to help keep Stack Exchange sites safe for the workplace and family-friendly.  If it was ok for answers, it should work fine for questions also.