# Hide post content if a user is destroyed as spammer

Tags: feature-request, moderator-tools, spam, account-destruction

There is a specific destroy reason for users that post only spam or other abusive content:

> This user was created to post spam or nonsense and has no other positive participation

Aside from deleting the user and all their posts, this specific destroy reason also feeds into an automatic spam blocking system. This means that simply destroying the user is the best way to deal with spammers and other abusive users.

Recently the behaviour of spam and offensive flags was changed, and they now hide the content of the removed posts by default. But this does not work for users that were destroyed without also flagging their posts as spam.

Destroying a user with the specific spam reason should treat all posts as if they were flagged as spam, and should hide them from view.

Comment: Yes - and if this can't be implemented for some edge case at least provide the moderator starting the destroy a list of all the user's non flagged posts so they can be reviewed / flagged before pulling the destroy trigger.

Comment: see also: [Obscure the title and text when question is deleted by Community from spam/offensive flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213201/165773) and [Remove links when a post is deleted by Community from spam/offensive flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131026/165773)

Comment: On a side note, I wonder why it is *other* positive participation.  Is posting spam or nonsense positive participation?