# Should the "Page Not Found" page for deleted spam suggest a search?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, deleted-questions, spam, 404-not-found

When a <10k user opens a deleted question, he is greeted with a "Page Not Found" page explaining that the question has been deleted by the author, or for moderation reasons, but more importantly it suggests that the user could search for similar questions or run a Google search with the title of the question.

[image: Page Not Found - Try searching for similar questions - Google search]

My question is, should the page suggest a further search if the question was deleted because it was spam? Should we be *suggesting* people *to search for spam*?

Comment: Totally agree, think it's even better to tell "This question was removed from ... due to spam/offensive content"

Comment: Aw man I can't wait to get 10k rep on SO and view that question!

Comment: URL please! :-)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/213274/

Comment: @3ventic: Thanks. BTW, get your love back Attract any Girl/Boy towards you with heart.

Comment: I just *love* that it includes the word *verily*. That truly is religious content.

Comment: @TimPost does change involving this mean [meta-tag:status-completed] for another feature request that looks related: [Obscure the title and text when question is deleted by Community from spam/offensive flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213201/165773)? Per my observations, it seems to be fixed recently

Answer (score 3):

Well, this has been applied hence the [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) in your list of tags... for proof, I have taken a screenshot of that deleted question you have linked in the comments:

[image]