# Should I be able to see the first few lines of a deleted post from my flag summary section?

Tags: bug, status-completed, tooltips, flag-history, deleted-posts

I don't have enough rep to view deleted posts yet. So should I be able to see the first few lines of a post **via the tooltip**?: (ie. rolling over the titile of a post gives you a tooltip with the first few lines of the post, just like hovering over a question on the main question page)

[image]

Yes, it's spam, I know, but there are more legit reasons for flagging - should a low-rep user be able to see a bit of this content??

Comment: Might be a bug, added the tag.

Comment: @ShadowWizard see also: [Obscure the title and text when question is deleted by Community from spam/offensive flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213201/165773)

Comment: @gnat true, but this one here is more "severe", as it allows users to see contents of any post if they flagged it. (not just spam)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I no longer see any tooltip when I hover over the titles, so this must have been fixed at some point!