# When hiding contents of spam answer, also hide or delete the comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, spam

For almost a year now, deleted answers that have at least one approved spam or offensive flag, [do not show the answer body but rather a friendly message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199969/152859). All Good.

However, comments are still being displayed and I don't think there can be any constructive comments on a spam or offensive answer.

Can comments also be hidden by default with a "show comments" link, or just deleted altogether?

The straw that broke the camel's back was [this spam answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238875/152859): (10k only)

> [image]

What's the point of hiding the spam/offensive content in the post body, if it's fully visible in its full ugliness in the comments?

Comment: I don't see the point in preserving them at all. Just delete all comments and call it done.

Comment: @AdamLear right, makes total sense.

Comment: Hmm. This makes me glad to not have 10k yet.

Comment: @Adam three years later, any chance to add such feature?

Comment: See also [this nearly identical feature-request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248646/comments-left-by-the-author-of-a-spam-offensive-post-should-be-deleted-from-the).

Answer (score 2):

To be honest, there is simply no need to comment on a spam/offensive answer: the comment will probably be seen by the OP and the extremely little few who should have casted their spam/offensive flags, and the comment will disappear in practically seconds as the spam post is swiftly deleted. Of course, we have the "smarter" spammers/ranters who use their commenting abilities.

So, I suggest a full deletion of all comments would be best or replacing the comments' text with a friendly message. Hiding the comments makes no sense as the comments are of course, practically useless. Comments should add value and be constructive: you can't add value to spam or offensive messages.

So... what now if the comments are suddenly deleted? Add a sentence to the friendly message:

> This answer was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown - you can see the revision history for details. Comments have also been removed.

or

> This answer was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown - you can see the revision history for details. Contents within the comments have also been removed as a result.

with the following in the comment:

> This answer this comment is under was marked as spam or rude or abusive and is therefore not shown.

---

So what's my credible source? Adam Lear's [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/238900/when-hiding-contents-of-spam-answer-also-hide-or-delete-the-comments#comment783030_238900):

> I don't see the point in preserving them at all. Just delete all comments and call it done.

---

If we want to go with collapsing the comments, we can use [Ilmari Karonen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/174699/ilmari-karonen)'s script (for SOUP - Stack Overflow's Unofficial Patch) from his [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/248653/278543) to this very related [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/248646/comments-left-by-the-author-of-a-spam-offensive-post-should-be-deleted-from-the):

```js
$('.deleted-answer').has('.hidden-deleted-answer').each( function () {
    var $this = $(this), comments = $(this).find('.comment').hide();
    if ( comments.length == 0 ) return;

    var ui = StackExchange.comments.uiForPost($this);
    var count = ui.jtBody.data('remaining-comments-count') + comments.length;
    ui.setCommentsMenu(count);
    ui.jtBody.data('remaining-comments-count', count);
} );
```

Comment: Don't take "credible source" too literally in MSE bounties; that really means either "make a good argument that SE will accept and implement" or "SE dev posting to say that it's been implemented".

Comment: Well, while I am looking for official answer, I am also well aware such answer might never arrive, and accept such scenario. So non official answers are also fine while they do contribute to the request or give new ideas. :)

Comment: @NathanTuggy It's kinda a joke. Instead of saying "Adam Lear also said...", I can make a little joke based on the bounty by saying Adam is a credible source

Comment: You're right - considering me a credible source is a joke. ;)