# The Markdown rendering on deleted content should be disabled or reduced

Tags: feature-request, markdown-rendering, deleted-posts

Deleted content, including content that is deleted via spam and rude/abusive flags is still visible to users with enough reputation (generally 10k+, I believe). I think the Markdown rendering of this content should be changed so that links are not "active" and images are not displayed. Ideally, the Markdown render would vary based on how the post was deleted such that content that was deleted as spam would have no active links and rude/abusive content would have no images. From a practical standpoint, just turning the Markdown rendering off for deleted content would be enough.

For example, on a site I am a moderator on, we have a user who is spamming/abusing the site with NSFW images. Our users are rapidly flagging, downvoting, and deleting the content and the site moderators are on top of the issue. I am hoping at some point the community managers (CMs) will purge our list of NSFW posts. Until that happens, a bunch of the posts on our front page are not safe for high rep users (those who can see deleted content) to view while at work.

It seems the system try to hide the content from high rep users if it has been flagged, however, mods are still presented with the content. If a high rep user wants to interact with a deleted post they would eventually have to look at the content. Further, users do not always flag and delete in the best possible way. By turning off the Markdown renderer users would be "safer".

Comment: Spam or offensive posts are already hidden (i.e the message seen [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/238900/307988)). Although I regularly see spam/offensive posts that aren't hidden. I guess the answer is to make sure they're flagged as such before deleting?

Comment: One thing to note - if a post has been deleted through spam/abusive flags it is already only displayed to those with diamonds. Regular users only see  something along the lines of "This post removed by moderation" and have to click through to see the actual post. However, I do agree that image should not be displayed to mods or when you click through.

Comment: related: [Obscure the title and text when question is deleted by Community from spam/offensive flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/213201/165773)

Comment: @Cai - yes, posts are only hidden like that if actually deleted through flagging. If flagged but deleted by users then they still show. Perhaps posts should be redacted if they picked up *any* flags.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132134/hide-deleted-answer-content

Comment: @ChrisF as stated in [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/199969/307988) I though posts were hidden if they had any flags. If that's not the case then they probably should, yes.

Comment: @random even if the content was hidden, at some point a user may want to see the content. To then get NSFW content is not ideal. If a user follows an offsite link to an image, well they at least have an idea what they are in for.

Comment: @Cai, Oh - I might be misremembering then, or getting confused between sites where I'm a mod and ones where I'm not.

Comment: @ChrisF Oded commented on that post that even a self-deleted answer will be hidden if it had flags so I guess it should be hidden, unless he's wrong or it's a bug (or you're misremembering) :)

Comment: As a mod you can redact. Isn't that an option in this case?

Comment: Collapsed is the same as reduced in that then you won't have people coming along asking why the formatting is borked

Comment: What about content that is drawn by ASCII text? 8====D ~ ~ ~

Comment: @random I am less likely to get fired for that...