# 7 day overkill flag ban

Tags: support, flags, declined-flags

I recently hit 10,000 reputation on Travel.SE less than two weeks ago so I am new to moderating deleted posts and the moderator tools.

## The two flags which led to the ban

I recently got a flag ban after two declined flags.

The two recent declined flags were as follows:

1. A user pretending to be Jeff Atwood posts a very rude answer
2. Deleted by community
3. Moderator edits it leaving:

> removed because it was too bad to even leave in deleted version.

4. I flag with the message:

> redact post history as very rude please

The reason I flagged with the message is because as the mod edited it, it needs redaction as otherwise what’s the point when you can scroll back in revision history.

5. The flag is declined with the following message:

> declined - Redacting is not needed, enough (or more than enough) action has been already taken.

Now, I raised two of these flags for similar rude posts by the same user both of which were declined which resulted in a 7 day flag ban.

Considering I’m learning and new to 10k moderation, the first time I’ve flagged a rude post for redaction (considering the content was removed by a moderator), I don’t see why that should get me a flag ban.

## What about the other 5 declined flags?

1 of those flags were a *no longer needed* flag on a comment which was later actioned by a moderator per [this chat message](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52335315#52335315).

So say 4 flags were actually declined, let’s look at them:

2 of the flags, I admit were mistakes. The other two were both related to 10k moderation. One of which was redacting a spam post (again still learning), which after was declined I posted [this question on Travel.SE meta](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/do-spam-posts-personal-information-need-to-be-redacted) and [this post on Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336492/do-spam-posts-personal-info-need-to-be-redacted). Now, I understand this flag was unnecessary. The other flag was also about deleted posts but I get it is also unnecessary.

So in summary, out of 7 declined flags:

- 3 I was learning
- 1 was later actioned
- 3 were my mistake

How can I learn if I get a flag ban? We all make mistakes at first, doesn’t mean they need to be punished like this.

## Helpful flags

Let’s see how many helpful flags I have over the past 7 days, **over 25**.

## What I suggest

In reality I had 3 actual declined flags were I just missed the make and wasn’t learning, does that deserve a 7 day ban?

I suggest deceasing the ban to 3/4 days or eliminating it all together?

This was even suggested by a moderator [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/52335790#52335790).

Comment: declined comment flags don't count towards flag bans. 7 days does seem an overkill

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: I really don't see why you kept flagging deleted posts to redact the edit history. Those posts are already deleted and inaccessible for the majority of users. There's only one reason (that I currently can think of): a legitimate question which just contained some accidentally posted secret information, like a password.

Comment: Daniil when you have 'mod tools' you are both expected to self moderate and know how things work. As you pointed out you made one complaint in the correct place and [received the correct explanation](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367/90750). A ban can be manually imposed. The way "Auto-ban" works is that despite having a '*good*' record (***if*** you do) if you suddenly start *running down hill* you must be very careful not to trip (the ban). Now, to the video:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cvuktushEhY

Comment: See also: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243600/282094